# Behavior of contains() and remove() on Set which is returned by entrySet()

Tags: java, collections, java-7, entryset

I have following code. Why contains & remove returns false?

```
    Map<Integer, String> p = new TreeMap();
    p.put(1, "w");
    p.put(2, "x");
    p.put(3, "y");
    p.put(4, "z");
    System.out.println(p);// {1=w, 2=x, 3=y, 4=z}
    Set s = p.entrySet();
    System.out.println(s);// [1=w, 2=x, 3=y, 4=z]
    System.out.println(s.contains(1));//false
    System.out.println(s.remove(1));//false
    System.out.println(p);// {1=w, 2=x, 3=y, 4=z}
    System.out.println(s);// [1=w, 2=x, 3=y, 4=z]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `entrySet()` returns a `Set` of [`Map.Entry`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/?java/util/Map.Entry.html) instances. So your lookup fails, as objects of type `Map.Entry<Integer, String>` can never be equal to instances of `Integer`.

You should pay attention to the generic signatures, i.e.

```
Map<Integer, String> p = new TreeMap<>();
p.put(1, "w");
p.put(2, "x");
p.put(3, "y");
p.put(4, "z");
System.out.println(p);// {1=w, 2=x, 3=y, 4=z}

Set<Map.Entry<Integer, String>> s = p.entrySet();
System.out.println(s);// [1=w, 2=x, 3=y, 4=z]

Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry = new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(1, "foo");
System.out.println(s.contains(entry)); // false (not containing {1=foo})

entry.setValue("w");
System.out.println(s.contains(entry)); // true (containing {1=w})
System.out.println(s.remove(entry));// true
System.out.println(p);// {2=x, 3=y, 4=z}
System.out.println(s);// [2=x, 3=y, 4=z]
```

If you want to process *keys* instead of entries, you have to use `keySet()` instead:

```
Map<Integer, String> p = new TreeMap<>();
p.put(1, "w");
p.put(2, "x");
p.put(3, "y");
p.put(4, "z");
System.out.println(p);// {1=w, 2=x, 3=y, 4=z}

Set<Integer> s = p.keySet();
System.out.println(s);// [1, 2, 3, 4]

System.out.println(s.contains(1)); // true
System.out.println(s.remove(1));// true
System.out.println(p);// {2=x, 3=y, 4=z}
System.out.println(s);// [2, 3, 4]
```

For completeness, note `Map`’s 3rd collection view, the `values()`. Depending on the actual operation, choosing the right view can simplify your operation dramatically.